# Error installing rails. Rails doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi Im creating an ec site in my rails.

My migration: (Item) has :name and :price. (Basket_Item) has :item_id(fk), :basket_id(fk) and :quantity.

The system User will add some items to their basket. So Basket_items is JOIN Table between (Item) and (Basket) see like below.

What I want to do:

**Get a price of Item and get a quantity from Basket_Items which is selected by user. Then I want to create @total_price = item_price * item_quantity.**

Can anyone help me to create the @total_price please.

This is my a try code but it doesn't work on rails console.

```
Basket_items

class CreateBasketItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :basket_items do |t|
      t.references :basket, index: true, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :item, index: true, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.integer    :quantity, null: false, default: 1
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

///

```
Items

class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :items do |t|
      t.references :admin, index: true, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.string  :name,  null: false, index: true
      t.integer :price, null: false
      t.text    :message

      t.string  :category, index: true
      t.string  :img 
      t.string  :Video_url
      t.text    :discription
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

///

This is my try a code but it doesn't work on rails console.

```
basket = current_user.prepare_basket
item_ids = basket.basket_items.select(:item_id)
items = basket.items.where(id: item_ids)
items_price = items.select(:price)
items_quantity = basket.basket_items.where(item_id: item_ids).pluck(:quantity)

def self.total(items_price, items_quantity)
  sum(items_price * items_quantity)
end

@total_price = basket.total(items_price, item_quantity)
```

Comment: Let's say you have a basket full of basket_items. You can get total price with `basket.basket_items.map{|r| r.quantity * r.item.price}.reduce(0, :+)` (not tested may need tweaks if some error arise)

Comment: The title of the question does not match the content.

Answer (score 1):

You provided only migration files, so my answer will be based on some assumptions:

1. `So Basket_items is JOIN Table between (Item) and (Basket)` - taking into account the logic of baskets and items, it means that you have many-to-many relation between Item & Basket through BasketItem as follow:

```rb
# basket.rb
class Basket < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :basket_items
  has_many :items, through: :basket_items
end

#item.rb
class Item < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :baskets_items
  has_many :baskets, through: :baskets_items
end

#basket_item.rb
class BasketItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :basket
  belongs_to :item
end
```

2. I'm not sure what `prepare_basket` on user instance do, just make sure that you get the right basket from this method.

With this configuration the total price can be calculated with one request as follow:

```rb
@total_price = basket.items.sum('items.price * basket_items.quantity')
```

or define it inside a model:

```rb
# basket.rb
class Basket < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :basket_items
  has_many :items, through: :basket_items

  def total_price
    items.sum('items.price * basket_items.quantity')
  end
end
```

```rb
basket = get_user_basket # find basket you gonna work with
@total_price = basket.total_price
```

Create some basket, items, and basket_items (this one will be created automatically if you create an item with `basket.items.create(params)`) in console and investigate the resulting SQL query:

```
SELECT SUM(items.price * basket_items.quantity) FROM "items" INNER JOIN "basket_items" ON "items"."id" = "basket_items"."item_id" WHERE "basket_items"."basket_id" = ?
```

[Read more](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) about `has_many :through` association in Rails.